# In Swift 2, how to cast a JSON array to [Int32]

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

I have the following code to read in a JSON file and then cast its arrays to either [Float32] or [Int32]

```
let location = NSString(string:"/Users/myname/Documents/test.js").stringByExpandingTildeInPath
let rawData = NSData(contentsOfFile: location)
let modelData = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(rawData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)

let dict = modelData as! NSDictionary
guard let vertices = dict["vertices"] as? [Float32] else {
    print("error casting vertices")
    return
}
guard let indices = dict["faces"] as? [Int32] else {
    print("error casting indices")
    return
}
```

The contents of the JSON file is:

```
{
    "vertices" : [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9],
    "faces" : [0,1,2]
}
```

The JSON file has been loaded and parsed successfully, however, the cast of `vertices` to `[Float32]` succeeds while the cast of `faces` to `[Int32]` fails. Is there anyway to cast `faces` to `[Int32]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `let indices = dict["faces"]` `indices` array  is created of type `Array<Double>` thus you can not type cast it as `[Int32]` or even as `[Int]`. You can try out following code to convert it to `[Int32]`

```
let faces = dict["faces"]! as [AnyObject]
let intFaces = (faces as! [Int]).map({Int32($0)})
```

`intFaces` will be of type `[Int32]`

Comment: looks like the first line of code should be `let faces = dict["faces"] as? [AnyObject]` in Swift 2

Answer (score 2):

Just cast it to [Int] not [Int32]. You can check the type like so

```
dict["faces"] is [Int]
```

Comment: Just for reference, what's the difference between Int and Int32?

Comment: This guy explained it well [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440100/what-is-the-difference-between-int-and-int32-in-swift#answer-27440158)

Comment: Something else I would suggest is to use swift's dictionary - [String: AnyObject]